# Stop python script running a infinite loop present within compiled c module

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, shared-libraries, keyboardinterrupt

I am an embedded C developer and very new to python so please bear with me.

I am on linux and have compiled a shared object module from a C Library and this C library opens serial port on a Linux machine and talks with a target over uart.
It does not do much for now and just prints data received over uart in the terminal.

The function in *myModule.c* is

```
void startUartComm(){
  openUart();

  while(1) {
    receiveDataOverUartAndPrint();  
  }
}
```

I have now imported this compiled module in my python script and calling it like below. I want to stop the python script from running in that endless while loop and I did something like this

```
import sys
import myModule

try:
    myModule.startUartComm()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> did not do anything but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> stopped the script.
But when I run again the script I get an error from the C library that the serial port is busy and cannot be used.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I could successfully  exit from the standalone C application and run it again without getting an error about busy serial port.

The question is, how can I stop the python script the correct way in this case thereby stopping my application as well.